# WordPress More tag doesn't work on Single post

Tags: posts, tags, single

When I add read more on my post (single.php) I can see < !--more-- > in HTML editor and when I publish it, I don't get to see it on my website.

I already tried several plugins to solve this problem, but it won't help.

On my single.php, I am using:

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

And code on my content.php is like this:

```
 <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
 <div class="entry-contentinside">
 <?php the_content( esc_attr__( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Mytheme' ) ); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I am Googling to resolve this problem, and found this code:

```
 <?php
 global $more;
 $more = 0;
 ?>
```

Only give a "Continue Reading" link with a blank link.

NOTE: 
1. When I am using < !--nextpage-- > , it's work. But this is not a normal way, since the button editor result < !--more- ->

2. The More tag is like [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/)

Can someone please help me.
Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you expect from read more in single post?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code please, this will work.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more..</a>
```

or

```
<?php 
the_content( __( 'more <span class="meta-nav">...</span>', 'themename' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: It's wont work. Not about give a link, but follow the WordPress's default about more tag. [Like this](https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/)